# Django create object - use default value for None

Tags: python, django, django-models

So I have a Django model which has few non nullable field with default values.

```
class Article(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(default=uuid4, primary_key=True, editable=False)
    code = models.CharField(max_length=200, default=uuid4, unique=True, null=False)
    company = models.CharField(max_length=200, default=uuid4, unique=True, null=False)
```

Now i want to do a

```
Article.objects.get_or_create(company=company, code=am_row['Article code'])
```

But here the issue is `am_row['Article code']` or `company` can be a `None`, and in that case i just want a new model to be created using that fields default values.

Currently passing None throws a `NOT NULL constraint failed` error.  How can i achieve this?

So i think this boils down to achieving

```
Article.objects.create(company=company, code=am_row['Article code'])
```

Comment: Do you give company and code? or it insert by default?

Comment: have tried checking if either is none and if it is just creating a new object and saving it like `obj = Foo.objects.create() obj.save()` ? That should use the default values. You could also check if they are none and just pass in the default values

Comment: the am_row['Article code'] was None. So it was throwing this error.

Comment: @Taylor in this case i have only two variables, but what if i have more variables, checking if they are None and passing is not good option .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can override the `get_or_create` method in your model manager, like this:

```
class CustomManager(models.Manager):
    def get_or_create(self, **kwargs):
        defaults = kwargs.pop('defaults', {})  # popping defaults from values
        for key, value in kwargs.items():
            if value == None:
                kwargs[key] = defaults.get(key)
        return super(CustomManager, self).get_or_create(**kwargs)


class Article(models.Model):
    # ...
    objects = CustomManager()
```

Then use it in your view like this:

```
Article.objects.get_or_create(
     company=company,
     code=am_row.get('Article code'),
     defaults={
        'company': uuid.uuid4(),
        'code': uuid.uuid4()
     }
)
```

If you want the default functionality of `get_or_create`, then use:

```
objects = Article._base_manager
objects.get_or_create(...)
```

Comment: but here what if am_row['Article code'] is not None. In that case i want to create the object with that value only not the default value.

Comment: Yep, my mistake. I missed that part of documentation. Updating my answer shortly

Comment: awesome , Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I'd use `or` operator in this case. Look at the example. If `x` is `None` some default value will be passed:

```
In [1]: import uuid

In [2]: def some_function(something):
   ...:     print(f'Something is {something}')
   ...:

In [3]: x = None

In [4]: some_function(x or uuid.uuid4())
Something is 518d7187-f74d-4620-90de-6104698a7d07

In [5]: x = 'Hello, world!'

In [6]: some_function(x or uuid.uuid4())
Something is Hello, world!
```

Comment: cool, i didn't knew we could use or directly while passing arguments